# How to use route for dependent relationship in octobercms?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, octobercms

I am currently working on a front-end form using ajax data request. In my code i have this in the php block that gets displayed in a partial when a category in select-box is selected to show subcategories.

```
function onChangeCat()
{
$this['subs'] = Cat::whereHas('parent', function ($query) use($cats){

 $query->where('cats','=', $cats );

})->pluck('cat_title', 'id');
```

I am trying to connect it to a route so that when a user clicks on a category, related subcategories get displayed in the second select-box.

This is my route file with #id of category select-box as parameter

```
Route::get('ajax/{cats}' , function () {

//
 return json_encode();
});
```

How do i connect the codes in php block and routes to work so that only related subcategories of category is displayed?

Comment: `data request` can not be combined with the `routes` as per design `data request ` will request **current url** and search for  `ajax-handlers` from current page, layout, partial [code blocks] ( onXyz() )  and `in included components`, **so you can not externally specify URL[route] for data request API**, IF you wan to use route then you need to do Ajax manually.

Comment: Is there a way to pass in id to the onXyz() without route?

Comment: added answer how to `pass value` to `ajax handler,` kindly check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass current element value to `Ajax Handler` you need to give it `name - attribute` and add `data-request="onChange"` handler. all other stuff will be handled by `October CMS Ajax Api`

```html
<select name="country" data-request="onChange">
    <option id="1">A</option>
    <option id="2">B</option>
    <option id="3">C</option>
    <option id="4">D</option>
</select>
```

> In your Ajax handler

```php
function onChange() {
    $id = post('country'); // as we name it `country` for select
    // ^ - this will be your selected value [id]
    return ['data' => 'some data'];
}
```

> Further process data **[ IF its needed ]** Other wise you can just use data-`request-update="calcresult: '#result'"` with returning `Html Markup`

```html
<script>
function myFunction(data) {
    console.log(data)
}
</script>


<select 
   name="first" 
   data-request="onChange" 
   data-request-success="myFunction(data)">
...
</select>
```

Up on `success-full request` this will call `myFunction` with return data in our case it will be `{'data':'some data'}` JSON Object, whatever you return from the `Ajax-Handler`.

if any doubt please comment.

Answer (score 0):

October CMS has a `$this->params()` method which can be called to get url parameters from the current request (see [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#routing-parameters)). Your code should look like the following (untested):

```
Route::get('ajax/{cats}' , function () {
    $results = Cat::whereHas('parent', function ($query) {

        $query->where('cats', $this->param('cats'));

    })->pluck('cat_title', 'id')->all(); 

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my questionm might not be very clear. The question should probably be "how to i create a dependent relationship using routes" In my code i can use a simple query in php block, and  foreach to populate the categories. Now the data request and ajax handler is suppose to populate the subcategories. Just want to how to do this using routes so that only related subcategories of a category is displayed.

Comment: @OsujiKingsley Do you need the actual ajax functionality?

Comment: yes, i have already added `data-request = onChangeCat`and `data-request-update="select: '#subcategory'"` to my category select and have my partial set up. Want to know how to connec the `data-request` to  the route.

Comment: Have you looked into the `data-request-update` attribute which will updated the specified partial on success? See [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/attributes-api) for more info?

Comment: @OsujiKingsley Apologies I misread your last comment, Is the `update` attribute not working?

Comment: It is working. Say when i change the query to display just all subcategories. Something like `where('parent_id', '>', 0)` for instance, it just displays all the subcategories in the second select box. But i want to limit the subcategories by the selected category. So for instance when "Fashion" is selected in the category selectbox, all subcategories under fashion is updated in the subcategories select box. That is what i am trying to implement using route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190246/discussion-between-thisiskelvin-and-osuji-kingsley).